# Firebase set error

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to set some data of a recipt using in app purchase

```
[ { transactionId: 'asdasd',
    orderId: undefined,
    productId: 'asdasd',
    purchaseDate: asdasd,
    quantity: 1,
    expirationDate: '1483asdasd387182781' } ]
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'recipts.blablatheoneendinginC12.google.0.orderId'
```

The method is:

```
ref.child('recipts').child(res.locals.user.uid).child('google').set(productsList);
```

And actually the database with the child recipts is like this:

[image]

Why is the error asking for orderId? I mean that parameter isn't event the request, productsList response or db structure?
I just wanted to insert productsList on recipts --> google child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `orderId: undefined` which is not allowed in Firebase.

Comment: I think new year party was so hard I don't pay attention on what I'm doin.. man do you know why could orderId become undefined from google?

Comment: oh I just google that stuff ... A unique order identifier for the transaction. This identifier corresponds to the Google payments order ID. If the order is a test purchase made through the In-app Billing Sandbox, orderId is blank.

Comment: why the -1 haha people are so fk n a s o l s maaaaaaan